# How to reference an interface that a parent class uses in C#?

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface that a my class uses. I have a subclass that I need to reference this interface with. I can not seem to figure it out, here is the code:

Interface:

```
public interface ICanBeCalled
{
    string NameCalled{ get; set; }
}
```

Parent class:

```
public class ParentClass: ICanBeCalled
{
    private string _name;

    public string NameCalled
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }    

    // functions below are omitted as not part of question
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class SubClass : ParentClass
{
    // Here I want to be able to set and get the name var, 
    // how can this be done? 
    // Ideally the set functionality would have it 
    // hard coded in a private string.
}
```

Comment: You simply reference it by name via a member of your `SubClass` class.

Comment: The `NameCalled` property is a public property of the base class. It's visible and usable in the sub class. Are you having issues accessing it?

Comment: If you want to access it by the interface (say the base class had explicitly implemented the interface and created a `new` and different implementation. Then you could cast `this` to the interface (`(ICanBeCalled) this`) and call it through that reference. You don't need to do this here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parent value in the constructor of `SubClass`

```
public class SubClass: ParentClass
{
    SubClass()
    {
          this.NameCalled = "MyHardcodedName";
    }
}
```